# How to force JSF/Glassfish to redirect on the same host?

Tags: java, jsf, redirect, glassfish, host

I am running two applications on different hostnames pointing to the same ip address.

I have created two virtual servers. Each one accepts requests from different host. 
The problem is that JSF/Glassfish moves me only at the first host after redirect.

Example:

server ip: 127.0.0.1 (hostname: aaa.domain.com, alias: bbb.domain.com)

**Glassfish:**

- **virt. serv. 1:** hosts: aaa.domain.com
- **virt. serv. 2:** hosts: bbb.domain.com

When i click on the link `<h:link outcome="/index?faces-redirect=true" value="home"/>` on **bbb**.domain.com, it redirects me on **aaa**.domain.com/index.xhtml

Why am I on **aaa** host?

How to force JSF/Glassfish to redirect to the same host?

Comment: In order to exclude JSF from being the cause, please look at the generated HTML output and share it if it's indeed pointing to the wrong host.

Comment: what do you mean by "I am running two applications on different hostnames pointing to the same ip address."...You are effectively running one application on 127.0.0.1 and using two different domain name to point to the same.